# Backup and restore in Office 365

Tags: office-365, backup, restore

I'm looking for official documentation regarding Backup schedules and restore options in Office 365.

More precisely:

- How often is backups made
- For how long is a backup saved
- How do you restore?
- How long does a restore take, is there an SLA for this?

I found [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/akieft/archive/2012/01/09/restore-options-in-sharepoint-online.aspx) from 2012 that answered some of the questions, but is this still valid?

Comment: "Backups are performed every 12 hours and retained for 14 days." according to http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2011/12/16/office-365-backup-amp-recovery.aspx. Note it was posted in 2011

Comment: That is the same info as in my link in the post, but it feels outdated.

Comment: Yeah your right... same content on a different TechNet blog (didn't notice that). You would think there would be more detailed info on this topic!

Comment: Truly! It is not unusual for Microsoft to be secretive about their operations regarding backup, disaster recovery etc. though

Comment: Another thing Recyclebin's default retention period changed from 30 days to 90 Days. http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/manage-the-recycle-bin-of-a-sharepoint-site-collection-HA102772732.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had this discussion with Microsoft Support in June 2014. They told me that backups are performed on all site collections on a daily basis and kept for 14 days. In order to get a restore to happen you need to add a service request from your Office 365 tennant admin center (support link in the left navigation).

[image]

Unfortunately they can only restore on site collection basis, which is quite big. If you lose a list or a document library, the only option you have is to restore the entire site collection.

However, there are options to use third party tools to make granular backup and restore if you like. Some of my customers prefer to have this setup to have the extra security since the cloud is the scary-out-of-control-cloud :-)

A week ago your link was referenced by [Microsoft Officials on the O365 community](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/271344.aspx), which makes it kind of offical.

Comment: OK, so we can possibly see it as still valid then! I guess lists and items can be retrieved from the recycle bins (they can be found there up to 30 days, so that is a bit better than the backup then)

Comment: @RobertLindgren True! The Recycle Bin is every admins friend and protection from hazardous users ;-)

Comment: Is there any way I can backup a document library in app web, in case someone uninstalls the app mistakenly?